# How do I change a link's style using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to use jQuery to have to change my hyperlink to bold upon clicking it and switch it back to normal when clicking another link. I have following links in my webpage:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li id="home"><a  href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id="test"><a  href="/tests.html">Tests</a></li>
            <li id="job"><a  href="/jobs.html"> Jobs</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
```

with the following styles:

```
#navigation { float:right; white-space:nowrap;}
#navigation ul{ list-style-type: none; line-height:14px; padding-top:20px; float:left; }
#navigation ul li{ float:left; display:inline; border-right:solid 1px #757171; padding-right:8px; margin-right:8px; }
#navigation ul li.last{ margin-right:0; border:0; padding-right:0; }
#navigation ul li a{ color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li a.active { color:#00e0ff; }
```

How can I change the style of selected link to bold and/or grey?

Comment: What do you mean by 'selected'? Do you mean the link that corresponds with the page that you are currently on?

Comment: selected means link click(while clicking the link it should be bold or grayed)

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the CSS to format the text or the jQuery to toggle between two classes?

Comment: yes...........i want to change the selected link text as bold and it returs the first state only after clicking another link

Answer (score 0):

> means link click(while clicking the link it should be bold or grayed)

There's no need to involve jQuery for this.

The `:active` psuedo-class will select elements while they are being clicked (and while Enter is being pressed while they are focused).

```
a:active { color: #333; }
```

Comment: it shows bold only clicking and returs to same before click back to another link....

Comment: it is also not working

Comment: @Sush — Yes, that is what you asked for. You said "while clicking" not "while visiting the page the link points to".

Comment: no i want to visit the page links ponits to

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$(function() {
   $('a.link').click(function() {
       $('a.link').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bmK7q/1/

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
jQuery('#navigation a').on('click', function(){
  jQuery(this).addClass('active')
})
```

Comment: FYI: this appeared in the low quality posts queue because someone flagged it. Your answer appears plausible, so I presume it is because it is a code-only answer.

Answer (score -3):

In your case:

edit: of course there is not :selected, i mean :active

```
#navigation ul li a:active {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: i edited. i wrote bad code;). Of course no quotes. I was just in js.

Comment: There is no `:selected` pseudo-class in CSS.

Comment: right of course. too early in the morning. i just edited.

Comment: while clicking the link it shows as bold and retuns to original state.i  want to retuns bold to initial state only after clcking another link